# define python imports only once for all files in the same folder, is it possible?

Tags: python

Suppose I do some data analysis within a particular folder. Some Juypter Notebooks some .py files. Is it possible (and does it makes sense) to define the imports globally in one file ? e.g. `import numpy as np` and now I can use `np.whatever` in every file ? Maybe this is a stupid question but a colleague of mine who is using R, asked me this question and I never thought of that idea.

EDIT: For the downvoters: I really tried to find that out my searching on the net but could not find any information. I thought that this would not be a good idea but who knows.

Comment: No that is not a good idea. You should import whatever modules you need, in each file you need them. No more, no less.

Comment: Thought so. Thank you.

Comment: edit: moved to answer

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be a 'good' idea in general, it could be a good idea for you. If you create a script in a folder with your imports and import that as a module elsewhere, you can import the other modules with it. The syntax would be `from my_convenience_imports import *`